# Is there a way to access all properties of a class without being a child of it

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I'm trying to make a table of all the sklabelnodes in my scene, the only problem is since i did this by using flatmap of an array its only the nodes that are added to the scene as children I'm curious to if you can access all of the properties that are sklabelnodes of this class without them having to be added as children of the scene, because some appear on certain occasions
i am currently retrieving the list in this fashion:

```
LabelSizes = self.children.flatMap{ $0 as? SKLabelNode }
```

Comment: What it sounds like you are trying to do is access all instances of a class that are currently in existence.  You can't do this without having some reference to these instances.  You would need to add the nodes to some object, such as an array, when you create them.

Comment: my problem is to add the properties to the list they have to be added to the scene i.e addChild(label) now label would be in the label sizes array, but not any other label nodes that haven't been added using addChild() i am trying to make the list contain all label nodes including ones that have not been added yet but have been defined as label nodes

Comment: You can add a node to your scene and an array at the same time.  Your problem is that you are building your array *from* the scene, so you will only get the labels that are in the scene